# CNAME to an external subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

I have a domain which is hosted at Cloudflair so I have full access to its DNS entries.  Then I have an external IIS website and again I have full access there.

How can I set the DNS up so that myhostname.mydomain.com redirects to https://site.myserver.com?

If I setup a CNAME with the the Name "myhostname" and the Content site.myserver.com it always directs to myserver.com, i.e. the root not the subdomain.

I then changed the bindings on the IIS site (myserver.com) so that incoming Hostname myhostname.mydomain.com would be bound to site.myserver.com but it still returned the root web.

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: A CNAME record doesn't redirect. It creates a host name alias. A web server needs to be configured to serve that name. An HTTP redirect requires a server at that address.

Comment: [You can create a page rule in Cloudflare to do the redirect on mydomain.com zone.](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/218411427-Understanding-and-Configuring-Cloudflare-Page-Rules-Page-Rules-Tutorial-)

Answer (score 1):

If the IIS site will accept the incoming Hostname `myhostname.mydomain.com`, then perhaps the simplest solution is to skip the CNAME record and create an A record `myhostname.mydomain.com -> [IIS server's IP address]`.

If you're using Apache, you can do the redirect you're asking about with the rewrite functionality in your site configuration file, or in the `.htaccess` file.